# PyTorch: Learning rate scheduler

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, learning-rate

How do I use a learning rate scheduler with the following optimizer?

```
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(optim_params,betas=(args.momentum, args.beta), weight_decay=args.weight_decay)
```

I have written the following scheduler:

```
scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=100, gamma=0.9)
```

I am not sure about whether I should step the scheduler or the optimizer. Which order should I take to perform the following?

```
optimizer.zero_grad()
scheduler.step()
optimizer.step()
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since `1.3` the behaviour was changed, see [releases](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/releases) and [this issue especially](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/7889).

Before this version, you should `step` scheduler before `optimizer`, which IMO wasn't reasonable. There was some back and forth (actually it breaks backward compatibility and IMO it's not a good idea to break it for such a minor inconvenience), but currently you should step `scheduler` after `optimizer`.

```
optimizer.zero_grad()
optimizer.step()
scheduler.step()
```